# Socks5 connection problem on telegram android

Tags: proxy, telegram, socks5

Because of censorship of telegram in my country I use proxies. Proxies(socks5) works fast on telegram desktop on windows but the same proxies doesn't work on telegram android on same network and I have no idea why this problem occurs.
Could you please help me about this problem?
Thanks a lot.

Connecting to telegram (android) via socks5 proxies.